# `QPochhammer` function simplification?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, products

Consider the function

$$(a;q)_n=\begin{cases}
1&n=0,\\
(1-a)(1-aq)\cdots(1-aq^{n-1})&n=1,2,\dots,\\
[(1-aq^{-1})(1-aq^{-2})\cdots(1-aq^n)]^{-1}&n=-1,-2,\dots
\end{cases}$$

which in *Mathematica* is denoted as `QPochhammer[a, q, n]`, and its infinite product cousin:

$$(a;q)_\infty=\prod_{k=0}^\infty (1-aq^k)$$

which in *Mathematica* reads `QPochhammer[a, q]`.

There exists the following relation among the finite product and infinite product expressions:

$$(a;q)_n=\frac{(a;q)_\infty}{(aq^n;q)_\infty}$$

which means that we should have

```
QPochhammer[x, q]/QPochhammer[q^n x, q] == QPochhammer[x, q, n]
```

> True

However, *Mathematica* does not produce any output for this input at all. Trying something like

```
QPochhammer[x, q]/QPochhammer[q^n x, q]//FullSimplify
```

does not return `QPochhammer[x, q, n]` either. It seems that *Mathematica* is completely oblivious about this relation. Is there any way to get *Mathematica* to simplify these expressions properly? In general, I am interested in giving *Mathematica* a ratio of two infinite `QPochhammer` functions and let it determine if a reduction to a finite version exists. Can this be done? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: AFAICT, *Mathematica* does not know this identity; it certainly is missing from `MathematicalFunctionData[QPochhammer, "ArgumentSimplifications"]`.

Comment: Would using `TransformationFunctions` be ok?

Comment: @chuy I guess so, but I don't quite understand yet how to use it here.

Comment: Mathematica can't be *completely* oblivious because it states this relation in the Details section of the help page of `QPochhammer`. Perhaps it's because the "infinite" side of the relation may not converge? Try `{x,q,n} = {3,1,2}`. This particular example, when simplified blindly, even leads to a false equality `1 == 4`.

Comment: @TheVee You are right! `q` is implied to be between zero and 1, while `n` is implied to be an integer. For other values the relation is not defined. Therefore, I would expect Mathematica to produce a `ConditionalExpression` object during the simplification. However, not even the following leads to the desired simplification: `Assuming[0 < q < 1 && n \[Element] Integers, 
 QPochhammer[x, q]/QPochhammer[q^n x, q] // FullSimplify]`. So Mathematica effectively behaves as if it was in fact completely oblivious of this relation.

Comment: Based on my experience with $q$-stuff in *Mathematica*, the symbolics still leave a lot to be desired. (The damn thing often can't recognize $q$-hypergeometrics as easily as it does for normal ones.) In that vein: do you already have a copy of [Koekoek and Swarttouw](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9602214)?

Comment: @J.M. Wow, thank you! This looks very useful as well! (I wonder why they make no mention of Macdonald, Koornwinder or Jack polynomials). Since you pointed out so many things related to special functions, I wonder maybe you know the definite answer to the question in the following link? I hope I do not impose too much: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811834/symmetrized-monomials-under-weyl-group

Answer (score 2):

It is even worse. While

```
FullSimplify[Product[(1 - q^k z), {k, 0, n - 1}]/Product[(1 - q^k z), {k, 1, n - 1}]]
```

yields     `1-z` ,

```
FullSimplify[QPochhammer[z, q, n]/QPochhammer[q z, q, n - 1]]
```

just returns the input. On the other hand,

```
FullSimplify[(1 - q) QGamma[x + 1, q]/QGamma[x, q]]
```

returns    `1 - q^x` .